# Auto calculate tasks in MS Project

Tags: microsoft-project

I have two tasks, named **Task 1** and **Task 2**.

Task 2 has two dependancies:

1. it must start on a specific date (later than the start of **Task 1**)
2. it must finish at the exact time of **Task's 1** finish **FF**

I created these dependancies without any problem, wrote them in **Predecessors** column, but the problem is that the duration of **Task 1** may vary, so when i am changind it's duration, **Task 2** is not keeping both of the dependancies, only the **FF** one. Even in the **Advanced** tab of this task i wrote must start on a specific date. 
I managed to to something, inserted another task between these two, let's call it **Task 3**.

I deleted any dependencies of **Task 2**, set it to **auto schedule** and then gave it two dependencies. **Task 1 "FF"** and **Task 3 "SS"**. Problem is that when i am changing the duration of **Task 1**, **Task 2** is still not auto calculating it's own duration and sticks with the **FF** function only. But if i click on the **Predecessors** column and then **respect links**, it's working. Anyhow, i have have multiple tasks like **Task 2** along the project so it's uncomfortable to insert so many **Task 3** workarounds ...

So, here is what i need from this task:
To keep the specified start date, to keep the **FF** dependency and automatically calculate it's duration if i will change the **Task 1** dates.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what to do:

1. On the Advanced tab set the Task Type of Task 2 to be "Fixed Work"
2. Link Task 2 to Task 1 with a Start-to-Start dependancy (include some lag if you wish to start it a fixed amount after Task 1 starts)
3. Go to the cell containing the Finish Date of Task 1 and Ctrl-C it to copy the date into the cut buffer
4. Go to the cell containing the Finish Date of Task 2. Right click, Paste Special and select Paste Link

You will now find that as Task 1 changes duration, Task 2 will also change duration to match it, and will always start on the designated start date (plus any lag you added)